# When a pthread starts does it need a mutex to access global data written previously in the thread that spawned it

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a c++ program on linux with two threads
Thread A writes some data to a std::map
No other data will ever be written to this map
then Thread A creates thread B
Thread B reads data from the map

So in this situation do I need to use a Mutex ?

If not then where is this guarantee specified.

Answer (score 5):

No. Thread creation is a synchronization point, so all the effects that the first thread produced before creating the second thread will "have happened" by the time the second thread is created (in a way that can be made precise in the language of the standard).

To be slightly more precise, in the context of one thread creating and later joining another thread...

- everything before thread creation *happens-before* anything inside the thread function, and
- everything inside the thread function *happens-before* anything after the thread joining.

Comment: +1 for mentioning thread creation serves as a synchronization point, which is probably the most critical issue here.

Answer (score 2):

No, mutex is only needed when you want to read/write to the memory from two or more threads simultaniously.
Since, when you have more than one thread, your std::map is immutable, you do not need any syncronization.
You dont ever need mutexes on immutable data.
And even if in your case thread B would write to the std::map, still only one thread would r/w on this memory at once and you dont need to syncronize one thread.

Comment: You don't need synchronization, no, but you do need a memory barrier for the previous writes to be visible in another thread. So this answer is very much incomplete.

Comment: Yes, well, creating a new thread would give such barrier in that case.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the dominant pattern, whenever possible, should be:

> (mutable) data moves with the tasks

So, data is owned by the thread that uses it. Now, it doesn't need to "physically" migrate, but using move semantics makes the picture a lot clearer:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

using Map = map<string, int>;

Map worker(Map&& data)
{
    for (auto& el : data)
        el.second *= -1;

    return std::move(data);
}

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    Map global
            { { "one", 1 },
              { "two", 2 },
              { "three", 3 } };

    auto background = async(worker, std::move(global));

    assert(global.empty());    // data now owned by the worker thread!

    global = background.get(); // await the result from the worker

    for (auto const& el: global) // now the data is owned by the main thread
        std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << "\n";
}
```

Note the `assert` in the middle of `main`: concurrent access isn't even possible.

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/209db9fe984ac52b)**.